# How ngSwitch works with ngFor and Inputs form

Tags: angular, angular-cli, mdbootstrap

Look at example below, **this code works well**(i found the example on some web-sites and made on my platform)

```
<div class="" *ngFor="let item of sellHouseFormsArray" [ngSwitch]="item.tag">
     <ng-template class="" ngSwitchCase="input">
              <div>input works</div>
      </ng-template>
     <ng-template ngSwitchCase="checkbox" >
           <div>checkbox works</div>
     </ng-template>
</div>
```

**However**, when i use **my code**:

```
   <mdb-form-control class="col-12 col-md-8 mb-4 mx-auto" *ngFor="let item of sellHouseFormsArray" [ngSwitch]="item.tag" >
          <ng-template ngSwitchCase="input">
              <input mdbInput mdbValidate class="form-control" formControlName="{{item.handler}}" type="{{item.type}}" id="{{item.handler}}login"/>
            <label mdbLabel class="form-label" for="{{item.handler}}">{{item.name}}</label>
          </ng-template>
           <ng-template ngSwitchCase="checkbox" >
             <input mdbInput mdbValidate class="form-control col-6" formControlName="{{item.handler}}" type="{{item.type}}" id="{{item.handler}}login"  />
             <label mdbLabel class="form-label" for="{{item.handler}}">{{item.name}}</label>
           </ng-template>
          <ng-template ngSwitchCase="textarea">
            <textarea  mdbInput mdbValidate class="form-control" id="{{item.handler}}login" rows="4" ></textarea>
            <label mdbLabel class="form-label" for="{{item.handler}}">{{item.name}}</label>
          </ng-template>
    </mdb-form-control>
```

**doesn't work!**

I don't know what happened, why code doesn't work.

Console gives error: **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'input')**

Comment: Just an idea. Maybe mdb-form-control requires input as direct child, without ng-template. So maybe try repeat mdb-form-control inside loop and switch like:
`    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of sellHouseFormsArray" [ngSwitch]="item.tag">
      <mdb-form-control class="col-12 col-md-8 mb-4 mx-auto" ngSwitchCase="input">
          <input mdbInput mdbValidate class="form-control" formControlName="{{item.handler}}" type="{{item.type}}" id="{{item.handler}}login"/>
          <label mdbLabel class="form-label" for="{{item.handler}}">{{item.name}}</label>`

Comment: @Nikolay Yes, it works. Please let make normal answer, I will confirm that! Thank you friend!

Comment: Thanks for update. Posted this suggestion as an answer

Comment: @Nikolay, ngSwitchCase is a [structural directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#structural-directives), so you can use `<ng-template ngSwitchCase="expr">..</ng-template>` or -see the `*` `<any-tag *ngSwitchCase="expr">..</any-tag>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea. Maybe mdb-form-control requires input as direct child, without ng-template. So maybe try repeat mdb-form-control inside loop and switch like:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of sellHouseFormsArray" [ngSwitch]="item.tag">
  <mdb-form-control class="col-12 col-md-8 mb-4 mx-auto" ngSwitchCase="input">
    <input mdbInput mdbValidate class="form-control" formControlName="{{item.handler}}" type="{{item.type}}" id="{{item.handler}}login"/>
    <label mdbLabel class="form-label" for="{{item.handler}}">{{item.name}}</label>
...
```